# To which sub-set does a repeat element of another subset belong in a Venn diagram. Or, when is an element not a compliment?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’ve started an introduction to probability chapter in a book I am working through and can not understand the books answer to a question about Venn diagrams.  I don’t have a teacher or a cohort to ask, so I’ve come here in the hope someone can shed some light on the problem.

The challenge is to describe the following sets:

> C = {C,O,M,P,L,E,T,E}

> D = {C,E,M,E,N,T}

as a Venn diagram from the sample space:

> Ω = {C,O,M,P,L,E,M,E,N,T,A,R,Y}

In the Venn diagram I constructed, the complement is:

> Complement = {A,R,Y,M}

But the book puts my complement M into subset $(C \cap D)$.

My logic is that $(C \cap D)$ should contain elements common to C and D and there is only one M common to both.

I’ve uploaded some pictures of my Venn diagrams and the book's answer.

[image]

Comment: Confusing example. Bad book. To define a set, you don't repeat elements. Hence $\{C, E, M, E, N, T\}$ should properly be specified as $\{C, E, M, N, T\}$. That repeated $M$ in the book's answer is seriously problematical.

Comment: My bad.  I defined those sets.  The book says “ A letter is chosen at random from the word COMPLEMENTARY and two events, C and D, are as follows.
C: choosing a letter belonging to the word COMPLETE
D: choosing a letter belonging to the word CEMENT
a Represent the events C and D in a Venn diagram. Ensure that your Venn diagram includes all the
letters that make up the word COMPLEMENTARY.”

Comment: Hmm. The question is more complicated than it looks. There are two Ms and two Es and so choosing an M or an E is twice as likely as choosing one of the other letters. Either of the two Ms you choose out of COMPLEMENTARY is one of the letters in CEMENT and also in COMPLETE, so both of them appear in the intersection. And while both Ms are "different", as they are separate events, they both match to the "same" M in CEMENT and COMPLETE. Unfortunately I am finding it difficult to explain it in rigorous mathematical language. Maybe someone else can join in.

Comment: After reading your response, I’m starting to see that the error in my conceptualisation to begin with was that I was looking at the Venn diagram as being composed of the letters from set A, set B and three letters from the universal set that didn’t appear in A and B.

Comment: So the key to constructing these diagrams in future seems to be to view all of the letters as having their origin in the sample space object, in this case “COMPLEMENTARY” and sequentially put them in.

Comment: Starting with C, C is common to both sets, so it’s in the middle, O is unique to C, the first M is common to both, so it’s in the middle, P is unique to C as is L, the first E is common to both, now the SECOND M is common to both as is the second E, N is unique to D, T is common to both and finally A, R and Y are neither C nor D.

Comment: In this way, M and E appears twice which should allow for the correct calculation of the theoretical probability to be made.

Comment: Yes, that is how I understand it.